# How to get DN and password with UnboundID

Tags: java, ldap, openldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I need some help concerning UnboundID. I heard it was a great choice but I'm not really used to it.

So I need to make a LDAP listener. On this listener, i should be able to catch bind request (from a ldap browser for example). I wonder how to get the DN and the password. Here is my code for the LDAP listener:

```
    public ResultCode CreateLdapServer () throws LDAPException {
       CannedResponseRequestHandler requestHandler = new CannedResponseRequestHandler();
    LDAPListenerConfig config =
             new LDAPListenerConfig(4243, requestHandler);
      try
      {
        config.setListenAddress(
             InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
      }
      catch (final Exception e)
      {
        System.err.println("Unable to create the listen server.");
        return ResultCode.PARAM_ERROR;
      }

    listener = new LDAPListener(config);

    try
    {
      listener.startListening();
      System.out.println("Serveur is listening ...");
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Unable to start listening.");
      return ResultCode.LOCAL_ERROR;
    }
    return ResultCode.SUCCESS;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws LDAPException {
    MyConnection connect = new MyConnection();
    connect.CreateLdapServer();
}
```

I read a lot of UnboundID documentation, but i can't find any simple example of what I need.

Also, i'm not really sure of the utility of CannedResponseRequestHandler. For what i need, is it enough ?

An other question: I'm not sure, but I have the feeling that my server is not listening OR i don't catch anything (when I connect with a ldap Browser, nothing happened). Any Idea / Suggestion ?

Thanks and have a nice day !

**EDIT :** Thanks to xhochy, I was able to catch the password and the username. As he said, I subclassed LDAPListenerRequestyHandler to override, first, newInstance then ProcessBindRequest. Here is the code (it's absolutely not perfect and it's still a beginning).

public class MyConnection {

```
private LDAPListener listener;

public MyConnection(){
}

public ResultCode CreateLdapServer() throws LDAPException {
    MyLDAPListenerRequestHandler requestHandler = new MyLDAPListenerRequestHandler();
    LDAPListenerConfig config =
             new LDAPListenerConfig(4243, requestHandler);
      try
      {
        config.setListenAddress(
             InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
      }
      catch (final Exception e)
      {
        System.err.println("Unable to create the listen server.");
        return ResultCode.PARAM_ERROR;
      }

    listener = new LDAPListener(config);

    try
    {
      listener.startListening();
      System.out.println("Serveur is listening ...");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Unable to start listening.");
      return ResultCode.LOCAL_ERROR;
    }


    return ResultCode.SUCCESS;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws LDAPException {
    MyConnection connect = new MyConnection();
    connect.CreateLdapServer();
}
```

}

Then the subclass of LDAPListenerRequestHandler:

```
public class MyLDAPListenerRequestHandler extends LDAPListenerRequestHandler {

@Override
public LDAPListenerRequestHandler newInstance(
        LDAPListenerClientConnection arg0) throws LDAPException {
        System.out.println("New Instance.");
        LDAPConnectionOptions option = new LDAPConnectionOptions();
        LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection(option, "yourIPadress", yourport);
        System.out.println("Connected to : " + connection.getConnectedAddress()+ " " + connection.getConnectedPort());

    return this;
}

@Override
public LDAPMessage processBindRequest(int arg0, BindRequestProtocolOp arg1,
        List<Control> arg2) {
    System.out.println(arg1.getBindDN());
    System.out.println(arg1.getSimplePassword());
    return null;
}
```

}

Thanks again !

Comment: Trying to sniff out peoples passwords?

Comment: No, I just need username and password to put them on a webservice which see if people are authorized or not.

Comment: But that's what the LDAP server is for! Your question doesn't make sense yet.

Comment: I don't really understand @EJP. I just need to catch username and password. With that, I can interact with my Web-service. I can't do something else, that's my boss decision :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should subclass `LDAPListenerRequestHandler` and implement `processBindRequest`. All the  information you are looking for is included in `BindRequestProtocolOp` (second argument of `processBindRequest`). Add an empty implementation for all other abstract methods.

If `request` is your `BindRequestProtocolOp` instance then you get your information via:

```java
String username = request.getBindDN();
ByteString password = request.getSimplePassword();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @xhochy, i'll check that today ! :)

Comment: The CannedResponseRequestHandler cannot be subclassed (it's final). So I tried with LDAPListenerRequestHandler and it can. I overrided to display the bind, but there seems to be something missing, my ldap browser don't communicate with the server.

Comment: Another try: You could subclass LDAPListenerRequestHandler directly and add empty implementations for all other abstract methods.

Comment: Ok, so I overrided the LDAPListenerRequestHandler to display the password and the username and it works (not perfectly with Softerra, but still). The thing that take me a long time to understand is that I needed to override newInstance() and to return this.
I'll post the code in my question.
Thanks a lot xhochy !

Answer (score 3):

Many LDAP server implementations will not return a password and many will not return a password you can use. (ie it maybe a hash).

I would be very curious why there could be a reason to return the password.

-jim